# Calling UDFs In Other Languages From SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, f#

Currently, I am trying to find out if there is some way to write F# or C# code in Visual Studio, import those UDFs into SQL Server, and call them from within SQL server. I know that it is possible to write functions in F# that can access/query the database from within Visual Studio and return results in Visual Studio. However, I am unsure if it is possible to, say, write a function in F# or C# and have a trigger execute the function in the SQL Server database each time a certain table is updated. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It certainly is.

They're called CLR UDFs (Common language runtime, user defined functions).

The basic steps involve:

1. Create a class library in your lang of choice (most examples seem to be C#, but that's not a requirement), and implement a function with a SQLFunction decorator.
2. Compile that assembly, and import it into sql server
3. Install each sql function from the assembly

Lots of documentation around once you know what they're called:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms131077

Answer (score 1):

Look at SQL CLR - you can build a .NET assembly to run in SQL Server